# progressbar and thread in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using thread and progressbar in xamarin android. I am using the following code for progress. But the progressbar is still showing after the thread has completed.
Could anyone help me to resolve this:

```
ProgressBar probar=view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
probar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
Button btnref = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnrefresh);
    btnref.Click += delegate {
        probar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        System.Threading.ThreadStart th = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(imagesetting);
        Thread myThread = new Thread(th);
        myThread.Start();
        probar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
    };



   private void imagesetting() {
        string uri = "example.com/xxx.svc" + Vid + "";
    -----
    }
```

Thanks in Advance,
Manthiram C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Make method that hides/show probar on **main thread**

```
private void ShowProgressBar(bool show) {
    RunOnUiThread(() => {
      ProgressBar probar=view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
      probar.Visibility = show ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible; 
    });
}
```

2) Show probar before starting task thread by calling **ShowProgressBar(true)**

```
btnref.Click += delegate {
    ShowProgressBar(true);
    System.Threading.ThreadStart th = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(imagesetting);
    Thread myThread = new Thread(th);
    myThread.Start();
 };
```

3) Hide probar by calling  **ShowProgressBar(false)** at the end of **imagesetting**

```
 private void imagesetting() {
    string uri = "example.com/xxx.svc" + Vid + "";

    *some code*

    ShowProgressBar(false);
 }
```

Comment: Hi Taier, It is working for me.Thank you for your help.